# How to show data from Google Sheet To Google Web App based on A Cell Value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, arraylist, google-sheets

I'm trying to show data from Google Sheet to a Google Web App based on a value in the Sheet's cell. So when the value is "YES" then user could see the table data, otherwise it shows rejection alert. To make it clear, here's the flow:

1. User submit a code that already in the Google Sheet
2. System check if the value in approval column on the code's row is "YES"
3. If the value is "YES", then get the data on the submitted code row in Google Sheet
4. Show the data as a table

I tried with my code, it could alert the rejection if the value is not "YES", but if the value is "YES" I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '10' of null

Is there a way to fix it? Your response will be appreciated :)

Here's a sample of my Javascript code:

```
function submitCode(){
  var code = document.getElementById("codeInput").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(view).checkTable(code);
}

function view(array){
  if (typeof array === 'string') {
   alert(array);
  }else{
   var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
   
   var row = document.createElement("tr");
   var col1 = document.createElement("td");
   col1.textContent = array[0];
   var col2 = document.createElement("td");
   col2.textContent = array[1];
   var col3 = document.createElement("td");
   col3.textContent = array[2];
   
   row.appendChild(col1);
   row.appendChild(col2);
   row.appendChild(col3);
  }
}
```

Here's a sample of my .gs code:

```
function checkTable(code){
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code); 
  var approval1 = data.map(function(r){return r[1]; });
  var approval2= data.map(function(r){return r[2]; });
  
  if(approval1[position] == "YES"){
    getTable(code);
  }else if(approval2[position] == "YES"){
    getTable(code);
  }else{
    return "Sorry You cannot see the table";
  }
}

function getTable(code){
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code); 

  var things1= data.map(function(r){return r[3]; });
  var things2= data.map(function(r){return r[4]; });
  var things3= data.map(function(r){return r[5]; });

  var array = [things1[position], things2[position], things3[position]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at Google Apps Script side, the values are not returned from `getTable()` and `checkTable()` while `return "Sorry You cannot see the table";` returns. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- As one more modification point, at HTML & Javascript side, `tbody.appendChild(row)` is not used. By this, the created elements are not shown.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Google Apps Script side:

```
function checkTable(code){
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code); 
  var approval1 = data.map(function(r){return r[1]; });
  var approval2= data.map(function(r){return r[2]; });
  
  if(approval1[position] == "YES" || approval2[position] == "YES"){  // Modified
    return getTable(code);  // Added
  }else{
    return "Sorry You cannot see the table";
  }
}

function getTable(code){
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code); 

  var things1= data.map(function(r){return r[3]; });
  var things2= data.map(function(r){return r[4]; });
  var things3= data.map(function(r){return r[5]; });

  var array = [things1[position], things2[position], things3[position]];
  return array;  // Added
}
```

HTML & Javascript side

```
function view(array){
  if (typeof array === 'string') {
   alert(array);
  }else{
   var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
   
   var row = document.createElement("tr");
   var col1 = document.createElement("td");
   col1.textContent = array[0];
   var col2 = document.createElement("td");
   col2.textContent = array[1];
   var col3 = document.createElement("td");
   col3.textContent = array[2];
   
   row.appendChild(col1);
   row.appendChild(col2);
   row.appendChild(col3);

   tbody.appendChild(row);  // Added
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh yeah I didn't put return and append the tbody.. Now it works! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.